# ASStream extension method not found

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

I am trying to write a metro style application to read data from a TCP stream. I am using Visual C++.

The problem is that the ASStream extension method cannot be found.

I have the following directives:

```
#using <System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll>
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices::WindowsRuntime;
```

ASStream is supposed to be part of WindowsRuntimeBuffer class in the  System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime namespace. But object browser clearly does not show that class in the  System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only native C++ is supported for Metro style applications.  C++/CLI is not supported and the .NET Framework is not directly supported from a native C++ component.

Comment: how are we supposed to call APIs like StreamSocket/System::IO::Stream from the application then ? I thought C++/CX was a subset of C++/CLI.

Comment: C++/CX uses the syntax of C++/CLI, but it has completely different semantics.  It is not at all a subset.  You cannot directly use .NET components.  You need to use the Windows Runtime APIs directly or other native libraries.

Comment: Is there a msdn link where the semantics are explained. Btw, why can I get the System::IO::Stream x = null to compile when I do the aforesaid includes ?

Comment: sorry, I meant System::IO::Stream ^bull = nullptr; compiles fine

Comment: Also, how to use the IBuffer interface that is returned by ReadBuffer without using the extension methods which do not seem to be supported ? Is there another way to read a binary stream. Forgive my unfamiliarity with the platform.